# What does `native overlay diff` mean in overlay2 storage driver?

Tags: docker

I experienced that a lower layer(diff) of an image which is associated with the running container is removed. (So, some files in the container are removed)

I think 'Native Overlay Diff' option from docker info is quite suspicious.

My docker info like below:

```
$ docker info
...
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
...
```

Do you guys know the exact meaning of 'Native Overlay Diff'?

Comment: I also see the warning message "Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: kernel has CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR enabled" when starting docker; some Googling eventually led to [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34342)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be related to the `OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR` kernel option, which is described in [Kconfig](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/36cd95dfa1ed76b59e2dcaafaa89c5479cec32b5/fs/overlayfs/Kconfig#L13) as:

> config OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR
>   bool "Overlayfs: turn on redirect dir feature by default"
>   depends on OVERLAY_FS
>   help
>
> If this config option is enabled then overlay filesystems will use
>   redirects when renaming directories by default.  In this case it is
>   still possible to turn off redirects globally with the
>   "redirect_dir=off" module option or on a filesystem instance basis
>   with the "redirect_dir=off" mount option.
>
> Note, that redirects are not backward compatible.  That is, mounting
>   an overlay which has redirects on a kernel that doesn't support this
>   feature will have unexpected results.
>
> If unsure, say N.

Some discussion on moby issues [34342](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34342) and [34320](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34320) indicates that, if all of the following are true:

1. the `OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR` kernel option is enabled
2. the storage engine is overlay2 (the default in most cases)
3. docker is storing images on a file system that is not mounted with `redirect_dir=off`
4. the "native" diff driver is used
5. a nonempty directory is renamed as part of a docker build, e.g. in a Dockerfile like the following:

   ```
   FROM busybox

   RUN mkdir /dir1
   RUN touch /dir1/newfile
   RUN mv /dir1 /dir2
   ```

Then the resulting image will not properly record the contents of the renamed directory (i.e., dir2 will not contain newfile) because the directory rename was implemented as a redirect using an extended file attribute (xattr) which is not understood by the docker archiving process. To solve this problem, when the first three conditions above are met, then docker will use the "naive" diff driver which produces correct images, but is slower than the "native" diff driver.

It seems like it is safe to ignore the warning, but if you notice slow builds, then you could try remounting the volume serving `/var/lib/docker` with the option `redirect_dir=off`.

Comment: Remounting `/var/lib/docker` wont' work. You have to use  `redirect_dir=off` module option for the overlay module: `modprobe -r overlay && modprobe overlay redirect_dir=off && systemctl restart docker`

Comment: Will there be any negative effects to doing `modprobe -r overlay` while there are docker containers running?

Comment: You can't reload module while it is in use. I set module parameter on boot  this way : `echo 'options overlay redirect_dir=off' > /etc/modprobe.d/disable_overlay_redirect_dir.conf`

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki I saved this .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d all right, but even so, docker doesn't use Native Overlay Diff. Can you think of any other reason that may be preventing docker from benefiting from it? I have a Debian in my PC where docker has it enabled, but in my Manjaro it can't. Thx!!

Comment: @DavidCardoso In recent kernels `redirect_dir=off` is not enough. Turns out kernels >= 4.20 enable redirect_dir when metacopy is on. You need to set metacopy=off redirect_dir=off as module parameters. See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d47748e5ae5af6572e520cc9767bbe70c22ea498#diff-315c61b86e39b9b47f4ab0cd9efc2467

Answer (score 0):

tmp fix

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/overlay/parameters/redirect_dir
```

then restart docker

```
systemctl restart docker
```

show docker info

```
docker info
...
  Native Overlay Diff: true
...
```

use this cmd to enable Native Overlay Diff